# Links in area Layout to Content\Css folder located in the root of ASP NET MVC application

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

Good morning/day/evening/night, everyone,

Asking for your ideas in dealing with Area in ASP NET MVC. 
My application has several areas, and each one has its own _Layout. How can I make links inside it to Css subfolder (the same with Scripts) located in Content folder in the root? Layouts from areas use identical css and image files, so I doubt I should create new Content folder inside each Area and duplicate identical files. Please explain how I should solve the problem. And many thanks in advance.

Comment: You can copy the same relative paths of the links from the top-level _Layout. e.g. `~/Content/Site.css`

Comment: @Jasen, please, post it as a solution so I can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the [virtual root path operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c#referencing-the-virtual-root-the--operator-and-href-method) `~`

The templated _Layout created for you gives you an example.

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
...
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Even inside an Area it will resolve to the root Content and Scripts so that resources, Bootstrap in this example, do not need to be copied for each Area.

Keep in mind this is resolved server-side.

So if you need to access it in script on a view page:

```
<script>
    var scriptRoot = "@Url.Content("~/Scripts")";
</script>
```

And in controller code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.BoostrapPath = Url.Content("~/Content/boostrap.css");

    return View();
}
```